# reducir codigo python

Tags: python, odoo

hola tengo este código pero se que lo puedo reducir ya que tiene las mismas variables solo cambia en el titulo efectivo y banco, me podrían ayudar?

```
  @api.multi
  @api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")
  def _total_cuenta_debe(self):
     self.total_cuenta_debe = sum(line.total_debe for line in self.detalle_documento_ids) if self.titulo == "Efectivo"  else 0

  @api.multi
  @api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")
  def _total_cuenta_haber(self):
     self.total_cuenta_haber = sum(line.total_haber for line in self.detalle_documento_ids) if self.titulo == "Efectivo"  else 0

  @api.multi
  @api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")
  def _total_cuenta_debe(self):
     self.total_cuenta_debe = sum(line.total_debe for line in self.detalle_documento_ids) if self.titulo == "Banco"  else 0

  @api.multi
  @api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")
  def _total_cuenta_haber(self):
     self.total_cuenta_haber = sum(line.total_haber for line in self.detalle_documento_ids) if self.titulo == "Banco"  else 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vamos a coger una de las funciones:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")
def _total_cuenta_debe(self):
   self.total_cuenta_debe = sum(line.total_debe for line in self.detalle_documento_ids) if self.titulo == "Efectivo"  else 0
```

¿que cambia respecto al resto? una sola linea

```
   **tipocuenta** = sum(**inputacion** for line in self.detalle_documento_ids) if self.titulo == **tipoingreso**  else 0
```

¿de que dependen?

tipocuenta e inputacion dependen de como se computa el ingreso, ya sea debe o haber
tipoingreso depende de como se ha hecho el ingreso

ahora vamos a sumarizarlo, el primer dato lo da la función llamada, el segundo debemos dárselo a la función

```
def _total_cuenta_haber(self, tipoingreso):
    columna = "total_haber"
    self.total_cuenta_haber = self._total_cuenta(columna, tipoingreso)

def _total_cuenta_debe(self, tipoingreso):
    columna = "total_debe"
    self.total_cuenta_debe = self._total_cuenta(columna, tipoingreso)

@api.multi
@api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")
def _total_cuenta(self, columna, tipoingreso):
    return = sum(getatti(line, columna) for line in self.detalle_documento_ids) if self.titulo == tipoingreso else 0
```

ya hemos reducido el código y cualquier cambio va solo a _total_cuenta
¿podemos reducirlo mas? lo cierto es que si, a costa de oscurecer algo el código

```
@api.multi
@api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")
def _total_cuenta(self, columna, tipoingreso):
    result = sum(getattr(line, f"total_{columna}") for line in self.detalle_documento_ids) if self.titulo == tipoingreso else 0
    setattr(self, f"total_cuenta_{columna}", result)
```

personalmente no me termina de gustar el ultimo método ya que implica que se ha diseñado algo mal, pero es valido

Comment: tengo un problema con el metodo realizado en un principio, ya qiue solo suma en una cuenta y no en todas las que tenga creado, como podria resolver ese problema?

Comment: eso es un problema diferente a la pregunta planteada, por favor haz una nueva pregunta con los datos para analizarla

Answer (score 0):

En principio, sin enteder el código ni la estructura de datos que tienes montada, yo calculaba en el compute los dos fields, el segundo caso, si es el mismo modelo de datos para los documentos en efectivo y en el banco, veo un posible error, pues se van a machacar los datos, pero bueno, aquí va mi propuesta

```
  @api.multi
  @api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")
  def _total_cuenta(self):

     document_details_cash =  self.detalle_documento_ids.filtered(lambda l: l.titulo == "Efectivo" )
     self.total_cuenta_debe_cash = sum(documnet_details_cash.mapped("total_debe"))
     self.total_cuenta_haber = sum(documnet_details_cash.mapped("total_haber"))

     document_details_bank =  self.detalle_documento_ids.filtered(lambda l: l.titulo == "Efectivo" )
     self.total_cuenta_debe_bank = sum(document_details_bank.mapped("total_debe"))
     self.total_cuenta_haber_bank = sum(document_details_bank.mapped("total_haber"))
```

Al final usaria el mismo compute para los 4 nuevos fields, reduciendo el código bastante.

Existen mejoras de optimización usando la función read_group

Comment: efectivamente tenias razon, recien me di cuenta que solo suma en una cuenta y no en las dos como deberia ser. Tienes alguna idea de como hacer ese metodo el cual sume en todas las cuentas que tenga que crea y no siga sumando en una sola?

Comment: Buenas @Francisco, yo crearía 4 campos, si quiero diferenciar que entra por caja o por banco, le doy una vuelta a mi comentario anterior para que lo veas.